# Random subsets of a set ; case of large sets

Tags: probability

I am aware that related topics have been discussed in other threads. However, not being an expert, I would like to know the answers to the following questions:
Let $E$ be a set having n elements ; $ |E|=n.$
$A_p$ is a subset of $E$ with $p$ elements $(1 \le p \le  n)$, chosen uniformly at random from the set of $\displaystyle\binom{n}{p}$  subsets of $E$ having $p$ elements.
Similarly, $B_q$ is a random subset of $E$ with $q$ elements $ (1 \le q\le p \le  n)$.
$A_p$ and $B_q$ are supposed to be chosen independently.

Questions :

1. Define $C = A_p \cap  B_q$, what is the probability distribution of $m=|C|$ ?
2. What is the expected value of $m$ ?
3. What is the probability that $C=\varnothing $ ?
4. What is the probability that $B_q\subseteq A_p$ ?
5. When $n, p, q$ are sufficiently large numbers, what happens to the previous formulas ?
   Example :  $n=2.10^9$ , $p=1.5.10^9$ , $q=100.10^6$

---

$\textbf{Edit-1}$  : based on Michael's hint :

Note that in all cases : $|A_p\cup B_q|=|A_p|+|B_q|-|(A_p \cap  B_q| \le n$
then $p+q-m\le n$

$\textbf{Question 3:}$ 
With $A_p$ being fixed, there are $\dbinom{n}{q}$  possible choices for $B_q$
If $C=\varnothing $, $m=0$ which is only possible if $p+q\le n$
If that's the case, there are still $\dbinom{n-p}{q}$ possibilities to choose $q$ elements not in $A_p$
to summarize :

- $p+q>n$ : $\Pr(C=\varnothing) =0$
- $p+q\le n$ : $\Pr(C=\varnothing)=\displaystyle\ \frac{\dbinom{n-p}{q}}{\dbinom{n}{q}}=\frac{(n-p)!(n-q)!}{n!(n-p-q)!}  $

$\textbf{Question 4:}$ 
There are $\dbinom{n}{q}$  possible choices for $B_q$
With $A_p$ being fixed, there are $\dbinom{p}{q}$  cases to get $B_q  \subseteq A_p$

Then : $\Pr(B_q  \subseteq A_p)=\displaystyle\frac{\dbinom{p}{q}}{\dbinom{n}{q}} =\frac{p!(n-q)!}{n!(p-q)!}  $

---

$\textbf{Edit-2}$  : By running some simulations as suggested by Jean Marie, I believe I have found the answer to question 1 and 2 by noticing that $E [m] = \displaystyle\frac{pq}{n}$

$\textbf{Question 1:}$ 
Let's further assume that $A_p = \{ 1,...,p\}$
Constructing $B_q$ : for an element of $B_q$, it has a probability $  \displaystyle\frac{p}{n}$ of being in $A_p$ and thus in $C$.
It is a Bernoulli distribution.
So, $C$ is the union of $q$ independent random variables following the previous Bernoulli distribution, and $m=|C|$ follows a binomial distribution $B(\displaystyle {q},\frac{p}{n})$

$\textbf{Question 2:}$ 
Therefore $E[m]=\displaystyle\frac{pq}{n}$

---

$\textbf{Edit-3}$  :

$\textbf{Question 5:}$ I am taking the orders of magnitude of $p, q, n$ to answer ; that is : $r =\displaystyle\frac{p}{n} = 0.75$ and $q = 10^8$

- A reasonable approximation to the random variable $m \sim B(q,r)$ is the normal distribution $N(qr,qr(1-r))$ ;
  $m \sim qr*N(1,(1-r))$
- $E[m]= qr =\displaystyle\frac{qp}{n} $  as already seen above.
- $Pr(m=0)\simeq 0$
- If $B_q\subseteq A_p$ then $m =q$ ; $Pr(B_q\subseteq A_p)\le Pr(m=q)\simeq 0$

Comment: You ask many questions which are more or less all consequences of the first one, but have you a little attempted to work on them ? For example by numerical simulation for the first question ?

Comment: If it helps, you may as well assume $A_p=\{1, ..., p\}$. Using this, can you do problems 3 and/or 4? They seem the simplest.

Comment: When you ask about the probability distribution, you need to define first a probability  space and a random variable on it. In (1) you mean that m is a constant random variable?

Comment: @Jean Marie I'm having some difficulty running numerical simulations for values of n > 10^7

Comment: But you do not need to go that far. Take a reasonable $n$ say $10^5$, and let $p$ and $q$ vary. It should give you an idea of the general pdf.